# Needing help with JSON problems

Tags: php, arrays, logic, json

i'm with this problem at PHP when i'm try to convert an array to an json
I have an recursive function that build the array to encode it on jSon format.

That's the array:

```
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'text' => 'lorem ipsum'),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'text' => 'lorem ipsum1'),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'text' => 'lorem ipsum2'),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'text' => 'lorem ipsum3'),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 3, 'text' => 'lorem ipsum4'),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent_id' => null, 'text' => 'lorem ipsum5'),
);
```

Thats my function:

```
function trataArray($data) {


$itemsByReference = array();

// Build array of item references:
foreach ($data as $key => &$item) {
    $itemsByReference[$item['id']] = &$item;
    // Children array:
    $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['children'] = array();
    // Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" )
    $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['data'] = new StdClass();
}

// Set items as children of the relevant parent item.
foreach ($data as $key => &$item)
    if ($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
        $itemsByReference [$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$item;

// Remove items that were added to parents elsewhere:
foreach ($data as $key => &$item) {
    if ($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
        unset($data[$key]);
}

// Encode:
return $data;
```

}

Thats my json, but this json have errors:

```
{
    "0": // Problem here... T_T
     {
        "id": 1,
        "parent_id": null,
        "name": "lorem ipsum",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "lorem ipsum1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "name": "lorem ipsum3",
                        "children": [],
                        "data": {}
                    }
                ],
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "lorem ipsum2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "parent_id": 3,
                        "name": "lorem ipsum4",
                        "children": [],
                        "data": {}
                    }
                ],
                "data": {}
            }
        ],
        "data": {}
    },
    "5":  // And here... T_T
    {
        "id": 6,
        "parent_id": null,
        "name": "lorem ipsum5",
        "children": [],
        "data": {}
    }
}
```

The strings "0": and "5": are causing an error on json markup.
i thinked to try to remove it using preg_replace but i'm terrible working with regular expressions. Someone could help me with it... :D

Thanks guys!

---

I had an idea... :)

I was looking for ways to test thins shit... :D
And i come with an idea, get the JSON from the plugin and ENCODE it as one array and print it to see what i would need to give to JSON Encode to give me the correct thing.

Them he reproduce it:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => City
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [text] => Wyoming
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 111
                                            [text] => Albin
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 112
                                            [text] => Canon
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 113
                                            [text] => Egbert
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [text] => Washington
                            [state] => closed
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 121
                                            [text] => Bellingham
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 122
                                            [text] => Chehalis
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 123
                                            [text] => Ellensburg
                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 124
                                            [text] => Monroe
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The JSON its base on OBJECTS, i think the bug its there, im tryng to work with arrays and convert it, when the data its an object.

Someone knows how to create something like it?
Just an way to i can think... Thanks guys...

:DDD

Comment: instead of converting the whole thing into a json, use a loop and convert each iteration into json.

Comment: p.s. be very careful using references with `foreach()`; see this comment for an example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#101425

Comment: i would think removing "1" and "5" would make it invalid JSON. why not build the original data structure the way you want the JSON data structure to be instead of trying to convert one data structure into a completely different one?

Comment: what plugin are you using to decode your JSON client side?

Comment: @dqhendricks - You're right, that's why i'm tryng to find another way.

Comment: @ken - Hey man, realy thanks by your post, i don not have shure about it, but will test. When we use foreach PHP creates indexes to control the variables or something like that, i read it once in an book...
Your post made me remeber it! 
i will try here, thanks.

Comment: @dqhendricks - I'm using jeasyui ui plugins
You can see the format from data json that the tree need to receive here:

And demo from plugin that i'm using
http://jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/combotree.html

The JSON data from the example
http://jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/tree_data.json

Comment: try this for your JSON operations: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [jslint.com](http://jsonlint.com/), this is valid JSON. It passes the validator just fine.

Comment: The problem it's im using an js plugin tree that need's to receive the JSON data without "0": and "5":

Comment: Yes, that json, minus your comments, is valid. How are you figuring out that its invalid? Or rather what problem is it causing/error message.

Comment: It doesn't  return any error, just don't show the tree. if i remove these "0": and "5": it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

How are you seeing the error?

Simply pasting your JSON directly into `<script>` blocks and loading that in a browser raises errors both in IE and Chrome, however, assigning the same JSON to a variable first prevents any error messages. The [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com) confirms these findings; when your bare JSON is run through compilation, it fails. When a simple variable assignment is introduced, everything compiles fine.

It seems there are some lexical rules of JS that I'm not aware of that is affecting this; sadly, I'm not sure exactly what the root cause is.

Also, I'm not sure how exactly you're producing the resultant JSON. I mean, I know you're using `json_encode()`, but no matter what I do with the array key, I cannot reproduce your output *using an array in PHP*.

I am looking to mimic this:

```
{"0": "foo"}
```

However, using numeric array keys in PHP will mean that the resultant JSON will be an array; for example:

```
json_encode( array(0 => 'foo') );
> (string) ["foo"]
json_encode( array("0" => 'foo') );
> (string) ["foo"]
```

The ONLY way that I can recreate your JSON is by doing the following:

```
$x = new stdClass;
$x->{"0"} = 'foo';
json_encode($x);
> (string) {"0": "foo"}
```

So, I'm thinking either your example is incomplete/misleading/wrong, or you've uncovered some extremely obscure bug in PHP.

Introducing spaces to the key, and other permutations like the following, also does not produce your JSON:

```
json_encode( array("0 " => 'foo') );
> (string) {"0 ": "foo"}

json_encode( array(" 0" => 'foo') );
> (string) {" 0": "foo"}

json_encode( array("00" => 'foo') );
> (string) {"00": "foo"}

json_encode( array(false => 'foo') );
> (string) ["foo"]

json_encode( array(null => 'foo') );
> (string) {"": "foo"}

json_encode( array("" => 'foo') );
> (string) {"": "foo"}
```

So, not sure what's going on.

Comment: i will try to attribute it to an var, but i don't think it is an bug from PHP, as @Michael said, the JSON that i'm providing it's valid. i'm think its an bug from plugin i'm using that doesn't accept the JSON as valid.

As i said, id doesn't give me any errors.
T_T

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with whatever you're parsing the JSON with, because the native parser in IE and Chrome both handle it ok -- so long as all the whitespace is removed. When you say, "The strings "0": and "5": are causing an error on json markup.", what do you mean? **WHERE are you seeing it "causing an error on json markup"?**

Comment: Imagine that you develop an plugin, and the developer will need to pass and type of data, you chose JSON. But your function need more then an valid JSON, your function need and valid JSON, and an JSON that corresponds to your pattern.

That's my problem, the json its valid, but the plugin works with an pattern and the "0": and "5": are breaking the pattern.

here its the plugin and the JSON that he work:
http://jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/combotree.html
http://jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/tree_data.json

Comment: PS: i don't receive or see any error because the plugins doesn't show it, but he isn't accept my JSON and don't show anything...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var $counter = 0;
foreach ($data as $key => &$item) {
    $itemsByReference[$counter] = &$item;
    // Children array:
    $itemsByReference[$counter]['children'] = array();
    // Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" )
    $itemsByReference[$counter]['data'] = new StdClass();

    $counter++;
}
```

This way you don't create an associative array and after encoding, it should not give you the "0" and "5" as keys. It will just be an array of objects.

Answer (score -1):

That is because you should'nt define the 0 to 5 as string. You should define it as int, so you don't even have to name it. Like this:

```
[
      {
           // This will be 0
      },
      {
           // This will be 1, and so on
      }
]
```

Comment: before all i print it using echo json_encode($data);
the strings 0 and 5 (i think) are added by the PHP, and not by the functions, so set 0 to 5 as string won't help